# Copy-initialization of simple RAII wrapper with lambda fails unexpectedly under GCC and Clang

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda, initialization

I've come across an unexpected problem while creating a trivial RAII wrapper.

Let alone the logical incompleteness of the code below (copy-constructor and assignment operator not deleted etc., this is meant to be an SSCCE), what strikes me is that *copy-initialization* of my wrapper with a temporary lambda results in a compilation error, while *direct-initialization* does not.

This behavior can be observed both on GCC 4.7.2 and on Clang 3.2, while ICC 13.0.1 and VC10 compile both versions without problems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    template<typename F>
    A(F&& f) : _f(forward<F>(f)) { }

    ~A() { _f(); }

private:

    std::function<void()> _f;
};

int main()
{
    // A a = [] () { cout << "Hello" << endl; }; // ERROR!
    A a([] () { cout << "Hello" << endl; }); // OK
}
```

**Who is right**, and what is the problem with those who are wrong? Is it an issue with the implementation of the C++ Standard Library, or rather a compiler issue?

References to the C++11 Standard are particularly welcome.

**EDIT:**

Here is the error produced by Clang 3.2:

```
Compilation finished with errors:

In file included from source.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/functional:1925:2: error: type 'A' does not provide a call operator
    (*_Base::_M_get_pointer(__functor))(
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/functional:2297:33: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::_Function_handler<void (), A>::_M_invoke' requested here
    _M_invoker = &_My_handler::_M_invoke;
                                   ^
source.cpp:9:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::function<void ()>::function<A>' requested here
    A(F&& f) : _f(forward<F>(f)) { }
               ^
source.cpp:20:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'A::A<A>' requested here
    A a = [] () { cout << "Hello" << endl; }; // ERROR!
      ^
```

1 error generated.

Comment: You should post the error messages in the compilers as those can help in understanding what the compiler is not *liking*. I don't see any reason upfront for the copy initialization not to work...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Right. Let me do that.

Comment: Hah. The code will compile, if we implement operator().

Comment: perhaps this recentish [blog posting](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.nl/2012/10/copying-constructors-in-c11.html) by Scott Meyers is of any use? BTW, he calls the `template<typename F> A(F&&)` a universal copy constructor, not a move constructor.

Comment: @rhalbersma: Thank you for the link, it seems relevant. I remember reading this post, but I kind of forgotten about it and I will definitely have to read it through once more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message (gcc 4.7.2) is reasonably informative:

```
c++/4.7/functional: In instantiation of 'static void std::_Function_handler<void(_ArgTypes ...), _Functor>::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data&, _ArgTypes ...) [with _Functor = A; _ArgTypes = {}]':
c++/4.7/functional:2298:6:   required from 'std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type) [with _Functor = A; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}; typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type = std::function<void()>::_Useless]'
source.cpp:9:32:   required from 'A::A(F&&) [with F = A]'
source.cpp:22:44:   required from here
c++/4.7/functional:1926:2: error: no match for call to '(A) ()'
```

The problem is that your class does not have an implicit move constructor available for use in copy-initialization.  The implicitly defined move constructor is deleted, since `A` has a user-defined destructor (12.8p9b4).

Add:

```
A(A &&) = default;
```

Note that since the defaulted move constructor is selected, the destructor should check that `_f` is non-empty; since the move constructor of `std::function` does not guarantee that the target is left empty, you should also perform that change yourself:

```
A(A &&a): _f() { std::swap(_f, a._f); }
~A() { if (_f) _f(); }
```

Recall that (per 8.5p17) a copy-initialization involves the creation of a prvalue temporary, which is then used to direct-initialize the target object.  The choice is between the template constructor and the implicitly defined copy constructor; the template constructor with type template argument `A` is preferred, since `A &&` binds to prvalue `A` better than `const A &` does.

An alternative (possibly better) is to disable the template constructor for `A` arguments:

```
template<typename F, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<F, A>::value>::type>
A(F&& f) : _f(forward<F>(f)) { }
```

In this case the implicitly defined copy constructor will be selected, so the destructor doesn't need to check the state of `_f`; however if the compiler does not perform copy elision then it (and `_f`) will be called twice.

Copy-elision is allowed (12.8p31); the non-elided form must be *accessible* (12.8p32) but as far as I can tell (and by omission) the compiler is not required to check that it is *compilable*.  So it is permissible for a compiler to either compile or refuse to compile the program; if it does compile, though, it must have performed copy elision.

Comment: So is there a bug in VC10 and ICC 13.0.1?

Comment: I don't see why that constructor should suppress either the copy- or move-constructor.

Comment: And btw, why should the move constructor be picked instead of my constructor template?

Comment: @GManNickG: It's the user-defined destructor that suppresses it. But I still don't understand why the move constructor is chosen rather than the constructor template.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Er, user-defined destructors don't automatically disable copy constructors, or the rule of three wouldn't be such a big deal. Also, template constructors are never considered for copy- or move-constructors. Which is why I'm confused these constructors aren't available implicitly.

Comment: @GManNickG: User-defined destructors do suppress *move* constructor though. I believe they don't suppress copy constructors just because of backwards compatibility. After all a class with a user-defined destructor has likely some resource to manage.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Hm, I'm less sure of move-constructors so that would make sense (I know this was a controversial area of the standard regardless). But in any case, the implicit copy-constructor should work just fine regardless.

Comment: @GManNickG: It's 12.8/9: *"If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if [...] X does not have a user-declared destructor, [...]"*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24140/discussion-between-gmannickg-and-andy-prowl)

Comment: @GManNickG sorry, it's not the constructor that's suppressing the move constructor, it's the *de*structor.  The copy constructor is given a non-const signature so is unavailable.

Comment: @ecatmur: No problem, but why is the move constructor required anyway? I think your claim that `std::function` is non-copyable is incorrect. And there is the same old copy-constructor available implicitly available in every class, I don't follow where the non-const signature comes from.

Comment: @GManNickG oops, don't know where I got that idea from.  The copy constructor is available, but the template constructor is preferred as it can bind better to a prvalue `A`.

Comment: How is `std::function` non copyable? Moreover, why is the constructor supposed to take a non-const reference? I believe this has more to do with the fact that the compiler is picking the universal reference constructor rather than the copy constructor(which is actually there and takes a const-ref).

Comment: @mfontanini yes, my misunderstanding.  Corrected now.

Comment: @ecatmur: technically the move constructor is not *deleted*, it is never *declared* (I usually consider *deleted* to refer to `= delete` which is a *definition*, not a *declaration*; the main difference being that a *deleted* function is still considered for overload resolution)